# Determine the equation(s) that define the affine variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $ be the curve parameterized by $(t^2,t^3,t^4)$. I want to determine an equation or equations in $x,y,z$ that describe the curve. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you see any obvious polynomial relations among the components of the parameterization? What happens if you attempt to use these relations as equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If you only want the result, you can use this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%20%7Bx%20-%20t%5E2%2C%20y%20-%20t%5E3%2C%20z%20-%20t%5E4%7D%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20y%2C%20z%7D%2C%20%7Bt%7D%5D), where  you find a system of generators for the ideal of the curve. You can justify that those equations define the curve. Perhaps a bit more complicated is to show that any polynomial that is zero on the curve is a combination of these basic ones.

$\bf{\text{Added:}}$ First, we'll find some relations between the coordinates of points in $V$. Say  $x^3 = y^2$ and  $x^2 = z$.

Conversely?   Take a point $(x,y,z)$ satisfying the first equality. Now, take $t$ so that    $(x,y) = (t^2, t^3)$:  $t=0$ if $x=y=0$ and $t = \frac{y}{x}$ otherwise. Now use the second equality $x^2 = z$  that implies $z = t^4$. Therefore $(x,y,z) = (t^2, t^3, t^4)$.

Conclusion: $V$ is defined by the equalities $x^3 - y^2 = 0$ and $x^2 - z=0$.

$\bf{\text{Added:}}$ Let's show also that the ideal of  polynomial $P(x,y,z)$ that are $0$ on $V$ is generated by $x^3 - y^2$ and $x^2 - z$. Indeed, let $P(x,y,z)$ a polynomial . First, by Bezout, the difference $P(x,y,z) - P(x,y,x^2)$ is divisible by $z-x^2$. Now, consider $Q(x,y) \colon = P(x,y,x^2)$. Divide $Q(x,y)$ to $y^2 - x^3$ as a polynomial in $y$ and get
$$Q(x,y) = (y^2 - x^3) L(x,y) + M(x) y + N(x)$$

Assume now that the polynomial $P(t^2, t^3, t^4)$ is identically $0$. Then we get $Q(t^2, t^3) \equiv 0$ and so $M(t^2) t^3 + N(t^2) \equiv 0$. Note that the first term $M(t^2) t^3$ is an odd polynonial in $t$ while $N(t^2)$ is even. We conclude $M(t^2)$, $N(t^2) \equiv 0$ and so $M=N=0$. In conclusion: if the polynomial $P(t^2, t^3, t^4)$ is identical $0$ ( i.e. $P(x,y,z)$ is in the ideal generated $x-t^2$, $y-t^3$, $z-t^4$ intersected with $k[x,y,z]$ -- the elimination ideal) then $P(x,y,z)$ is a combination of  $x^3 - y^2$ and $x^2 - z$.

Comment: I think the suggestion of @KReiser is more useful, since Wolfram’s literal response was not algebraic.

Comment: @Lubin: The result given by Wolfram seems to be $\{y^4-z^3, x z-y^2, x y^2-z^2, x^2-z\}$ - the elimination ideal. One could reverse engineer. But you are correct. I will attempt an honest solution.

Comment: When I followed the link, I saw fractional exponents, which annoyed me. I like your fuller explanation.